# program to generate fibonacci series through pipe system call

Tags: c, unix, operating-system, fibonacci

This code is to accept no. of terms of fibonacci series in child process creating an array and redirecting through pipe the output to parent. Parent has to wait till child generates fibonacci series.
the recieved text is always showing -1 whereas the sent text is displaying the number of inputted integers *4 which is fine.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<string.h>

int* fibo(int n)
{
    int* a=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    *(a+0)=0;
    *(a+1)=1;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n-2;i++)
    {
        *(a+i+2)=*(a+i)+(*(a+i+1));
    }
    return a;
    }


    int main()
    {
        int* fib;
        int fd[2];
        pid_t childpid;
        int n,nb;

        int k=pipe(fd);
        if(k==-1)
        {
        printf("Pipe failed");
        return 0;
    }

    childpid=fork();
    if(childpid == 0) 
    {
        printf("Enter no. of fibonacci numbers");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        fib=fibo(n);
        close(fd[0]);
        nb=(fd[1],fib,n*sizeof(int));
        printf("Sent string: %d \n",nb);
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        wait();
        close(fd[1]);
        nb= read(fd[0],fib,n*sizeof(int));
        printf("Received string: %d ",nb);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should fix the whitespace in the code, it's very hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a separate buffer for reading.

```
int buffer[n];
nb= read(fd[0],buffer,n*sizeof(int));
```

You need not do a `wait()` in the parent process

Comment: still doesnt work i used separate buffer and gave input 5 so it displays sent:20 recieved:0

Comment: thanks that worked. i was actually using sizeof(buffer) which was not working.